# Encoding converting PHP

Tags: php, encoding

I need help with encoding :(
I have parsed string from site: Ëè÷íûå âñòðå÷è 
My site is in UTF-8 encoding.

How to convert parsed string to encoding of my site?
On this site artlebedev.ru/tools/decoder 
When I click on "Расшифровать" button, I get right result: Личные встречи.

Comment: Have you tried using `iconv`?

Comment: Yes... I tried. I tried everything :(

Comment: If you have a string and you know the source encoding, you can use `iconv` and print it as is on your website (assuming you set the correct content type on your page). If that doesn't work, the source encoding is different than what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

this does not work you say?

```
echo iconv("iso-8859-5","utf-8","Ëè÷íûå âñòðå÷è");
```

then are you sure your **file** is utf8 also?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
echo iconv("cp1251","utf8",iconv("utf8","cp1252","Ëè÷íûå âñòðå÷è"));
```